# solr newly added documents on indexes not reflected before restart

Tags: ruby, indexing, solr, full-text-search, rsolr

I am facing the strange behavior with solr insertion. Newly added documents never reflected in index. i have to restart the solr app instance in glassfish server to get the updates. This is happening all the time. Initially i was using lucene and it was fine.

i am not sure what messed up here, i verified everything and it seems ok. But i want to know is this how solr functions, like it takes some time to update the index after the new insert. Because it never reflected in index after long times(just 10 docs).

has anyone got an idea how to fix this?

**Update**: I am using [rsolr](https://github.com/mwmitchell/rsolr) ruby wrapper for connecting to solr

Comment: did you commit after inserting these new documents?

Comment: nope, i am using the ruby wrapper (rsolr), it doesnt have any specific methods for commit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commit after making changes to the index. [Here's how to do it in rsolr](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rsolr/1.0.2/file/README.rdoc#Commit___Optimize).

Alternatively, set up [autoCommit](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#Update_Handler_Section).